# Do laptops with the same specs but different sizes have the same performance?

Tags: laptop

I'm considering two different MSI-G series laptops. Some are 15.6" and some are 17.8". Some of them have the same CPU, but a big difference in price. I'm wondering whether they reduced the performance from of the CPU and GPU on the 15.6" ones.

Do they have similar performance on games etc, or might size cause significant difference?

Comment: if the resolution is the same, size won't matter

Comment: Perhaps the smaller model would have less efficient heat dissipation, thus reducing performance

Answer (score 2):

CPU is not the only specification that affects performance. Factors to consider include:

- Is the CPU the exact same model? There are many different types of Core-i5 processors, for example, and they may have different performance and power consumption.
- Do they have the exact same graphics chips? Check to see if the price difference may be due to one having a discrete graphics card.
- How much RAM do they have?
- How big is the hard disk? How fast is it (i.e. 5400 rpm or 7200 rpm)? Do any of them have an SSD? Those can factor into expense and performance.
- What is the screen resolution? The higher the resolution, the harder the GPU has to work to render the display. Also, regardless of resolution, a bigger screen requires more power to light.
- Do they have any other differences that might cause the difference in price? A larger laptop may require more raw material to build, since it's larger, thus raising price. On the other hand, smaller laptops may be more expensive to build because components have to be smaller to fit everything into a smaller space with the same performance.

Overall, laptop size does not *directly* affect performance, but there are a variety of other factors that go into cost and performance that may not be immediately apparent.

Answer (score 1):

You would not see a performance difference if the resolution between the two screens were the same.

However, the refresh rate or "tearing" could vary between the two that some may confuse for performance. It is not a performance issue, but rather the nature of the monitor. Vertical Sync would need to be enabled within a game to "fix" this. Whenever you enable vertical sync, it could impact performance and also limit your FPS to 60.